# Global Settings in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that have to be *customisable* and one parameter is the root of the url. The app ain't necessarily at the root of the website, ie. it can be hosted at http://onedomain.com/index.html, where the `appName` would be `/`, as it can be hosted at http://anotherdomain.com/myapp/index.html, where the `appName` would be `/myapp/`.

But I need to know the `appName` in the router, so in the `configFn` of my module, to do this kind of stuff:

```
return $routeProvider.when(appName + "index.html", {
  templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```

As I have more parameters, I started a service I called `Settings` but you can't inject services while configuring a module…

What would you do?

For my concern, I started thinking about a custom provider but I'm not sure it's appropriate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `Settings` related information, I use [constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant):

```
angular.module(...)
  .constant("APPNAME", "/myapp/")
  .controller(..., function(..., APPNAME) {...})
```

Here is a [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ym3Nlsm1nX4wPaiuVQ3Y?p=preview) to illustrate constant.

Comment: I discovered `constant` few minutes after I asked my question. But your example is way clearer than Angular doc :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.when('/'` and `<base href="/myapp/" />`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I forgot about this. I will pick for @marcoseu answer since it's great in a more generic way.

Comment: having a general constant to have a "base path" is just insane

Comment: Obviously, and hopefully, I'm not just doing that. I do have more constants.